# How to test Rails create action with nested attributes and FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot

I have a model that accepts an `invoice` and its nested `items`:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items

  attr_accessible :number, :date, :recipient, :project_id, :items_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => :all_blank

end
```

I find it very difficult to test this with RSpec and FactoryGirl, though. This is what I've got:

```
describe 'POST #create' do

  context "with valid attributes" do

    it "saves the new invoice in the database" do
      expect {
        post :create, invoice: attributes_for(:invoice), items_attributes: [ attributes_for(:item), attributes_for(:item) ]
      }.to change(Invoice, :count).by(1)        
    end

  end

end
```

This is my create action in the controller:

```
def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.build(params[:invoice])
  if @invoice.save
    flash[:success] = "Invoice created."
    redirect_to invoices_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: items`

Can anybody help me out on this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

First: `items` are nested, so their name in params is `items_attributes`. Change it.

Second: Nested means... nested!

Basically, replace:

```
post :create, invoice: attributes_for(:invoice, items: [ build(:item), build(:item) ])
```

with:

```
post :create, invoice: { attributes_for(:invoice).merge(items_attributes: [ attributes_for(:item), attributes_for(:item) ]) }
```

SideNote, you're doing a real integration test here, you could stub to keep unit tests.

Comment: Ah that looks much better than my version already, thanks. Your line causes a syntax error here, though, so I removed the rounded brackets. That way, the test runs but still throws the same error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: items`

Comment: syntax is correct, see ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. There is no `item` in the params I wrote, I guess you misspelled something

Comment: Hm strange, I had to remove the rounded brackets again to get it to work. Now the test runs, but throws the same error as before. No chance of any typos since I just copied your line.

Comment: I guess atributes_for invites undesirable attributes, could you copy paste the params received by the controller?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but where can I get those params from? I may have found a solution by changing my FactoryGirl file. I need to go now, but if you could have a look at this thread again later, that would be fantastic.

Comment: add a debugging line in your controller and check the params

Comment: Hello again, I spent a couple more hours yesterday evening twisting and tweaking my code (thanks to your help). Most tests do get passed now, except for the ones related to the **POST create** action. I decided to open a [new thread for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311734/how-to-test-a-nested-form-with-rspec-and-factorygirl). Would be nice if you could take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem so I created a patch that adds a FactoryGirl.nested_attributes_for method to FactoryGirl:

```
module FactoryGirl
  def self.nested_attributes_for(factory_sym)
    attrs = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(factory_sym)
    factory = FactoryGirl.factories[factory_sym]
    factory.associations.names.each do |sym|
      attrs["#{sym}_attributes"] = FactoryGirl.attributes_for sym
    end
    return attrs
  end
end
```

so now you can call:

```
post :create, invoice: FactoryGirl.nested_attributes_for(:invoice) }
```

and you'll get all that nested form goodness you know and love :)

(To apply the patch you need to copy that code at the top of my answer in to a new file in your config/initializers folder)

Comment: This worked very well for me. I think it should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the great code